# Eliminating duplicate values based on only one column of the table

Tags: sql, sql-server, distinct, inner-join, duplicates

My query:

```
SELECT sites.siteName, sites.siteIP, history.date
FROM sites INNER JOIN
     history ON sites.siteName = history.siteName
ORDER BY siteName,date
```

First part of the output:

[image]

How can I remove the duplicates in `siteName` column? I want to leave only the updated one based on `date` column.

In the example output above, I need the rows 1, 3, 6, 10

Answer (score 72, accepted):

This is where the window function `row_number()` comes in handy:

```
SELECT s.siteName, s.siteIP, h.date
FROM sites s INNER JOIN
     (select h.*, row_number() over (partition by siteName order by date desc) as seqnum
      from history h
     ) h
    ON s.siteName = h.siteName and seqnum = 1
ORDER BY s.siteName, h.date
```

Comment: Could you explain the query a bit?

Comment: @JacksOnF1re . . . Do you know what `row_number()` does?  It enumerates rows in a group (defined by the `partition by` clause).  The ordering is based on the `order by` clause.  By selecting the value of 1, only one row is chosen per group, and that will be the one with the biggest date.

Comment: Wow, it took Gordon 2 min to come up with this. smh.

Comment: steve-o you are implying he saw the post straight away haha. It probably took it a minute or less. Super impressive

Comment: What about `INNER JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT h.siteName FROM history h) ON ...`? In my case it produced identical results

Answer (score 10):

From your example it seems reasonable to assume that the `siteIP` column is determined by the `siteName` column (that is, each site has only one `siteIP`). If this is indeed the case, then there is a simple solution using `group by`:

```
select
  sites.siteName,
  sites.siteIP,
  max(history.date)
from sites
inner join history on
  sites.siteName=history.siteName
group by
  sites.siteName,
  sites.siteIP
order by
  sites.siteName;
```

However, if my assumption is not correct (that is, it is possible for a site to have multiple `siteIP`), then it is not clear from you question which `siteIP` you want the query to return in the second column. If just any `siteIP`, then the following query will do:

```
select
  sites.siteName,
  min(sites.siteIP),
  max(history.date)
from sites
inner join history on
  sites.siteName=history.siteName
group by
  sites.siteName
order by
  sites.siteName;
```

Answer (score 0):

I solve such queries using this pattern:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM t
WHERE t.field=(
  SELECT MAX(t.field) 
  FROM t AS t0 
  WHERE t.group_column1=t0.group_column1
    AND t.group_column2=t0.group_column2 ...)
```

That is it will select records where the value of a field is at its max value. To apply it to your query I used the common table expression so that I don't have to repeat the JOIN twice:

```sql
WITH site_history AS (
  SELECT sites.siteName, sites.siteIP, history.date
  FROM sites
  JOIN history USING (siteName)
)
SELECT *
FROM site_history h
WHERE date=(
  SELECT MAX(date) 
  FROM site_history h0 
  WHERE h.siteName=h0.siteName)
ORDER BY siteName
```

It's important to note that it works only if the field we're calculating the maximum for is unique. In your example the `date` field should be unique for each `siteName`, that is if the IP can't be changed multiple times per millisecond. In my experience this is commonly the case otherwise you don't know which record is the newest anyway. If the `history` table has an unique index for `(site, date)`, this query is also very fast, index range scan on the `history` table scanning just the first item can be used.