# Remove duplicate values based on only one column of the table

Tags: sql, database

I am making a table where there is a specific column that needs to contain Unique Values, I'm trying to use the solution from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17507887/eliminating-duplicate-values-based-on-only-one-column-of-the-table) question. However I can't seem to work it out correctly.

Here's my SQL:

```
SELECT DISTINCT tabArtikel.ArtCode, tabArtikelLeverancierDetail.AldArtCodeBijLeverancier,
       tabArtikel.ArtOms, vwKMBVoorraad.MagVoorraad, vwKMBVoorraad.LocNaam,
       tabArtikelLeverancierDetail.AldInkoopPrijs, tabVoorraadMutatie.VrdMutDatum, tabNawFile.NawFilNummer
FROM KingSystem.tabArtikel tabArtikel,
     KingSystem.tabArtikelLeverancier tabArtikelLeverancier,
     KingSystem.tabArtikelLeverancierDetail tabArtikelLeverancierDetail,
     KingSystem.tabNawFile tabNawFile,
     KingSystem.tabVoorraadMutatie tabVoorraadMutatie,
     KingSystem.vwKMBVoorraad vwKMBVoorraad
WHERE vwKMBVoorraad.ArtGid = tabArtikel.ArtGid
  AND tabArtikelLeverancier.ArtLevArtGid = tabArtikel.ArtGid
  AND tabArtikelLeverancierDetail.AldArtLevGid = tabArtikelLeverancier.ArtLevGid
  AND tabVoorraadMutatie.VrdMutArtGid = tabArtikel.ArtGid
  AND tabNawFile.NawFilNawGid = tabArtikelLeverancier.ArtLevNawGid
  AND ((vwKMBVoorraad.MagVoorraad>0) AND (tabArtikel.ArtCode Not Like 'V%'))
ORDER BY tabVoorraadMutatie.VrdMutDatum DESC
```

Now, one more thing. The date of VrdMutDatum needs to be sorted to descending first, before the ArtCode duplicate values get removed.

I don't know if this was all the necessary information, so if you need me to post anything else other then the above, then let me know

P.S. I'm doing this because the output contains 125K+ rows, when it should only have 5k rows

My attempt on implementing the code from the link above:

```
SELECT tabArtikel.ArtCode, tabVoorraadMutatie.VrdMutDatum
FROM KingSystem.tabArtikel INNER JOIN
            (SELECT tabVoorraadMutatie.*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ArtCode ORDER BY date DESC) AS seqnum)
            FROM history tabVoorraadMutatie
            ) tabArtikel, KingSystem.tabVoorraadMutatie tabVoorraadMutatie
WHERE tabArtikel.ArtGid = tabVoorraadMutatie.VrdMutArtGid
ON tabArtikel.ArtCode = tabVoorraadMutatie.VrdMutDatum AND seqnum = 1
ORDER BY tabArtikel.ArtCode, tabVoorraadMutatie.date
```

Comment: Tip 1: shorter table aliases!

Comment: Tip 2: use proper join syntax!

Comment: @fancyPants do you mean INNER JOIN? I tried using the code from the link I posted in the message, but it doesnt help. I edited it to this: (section underneath P.S.)

Comment: 0) what is the *purpose* of this query? 1) what are the (key)fields that the result should be unique on? 2) which keyfield(s) cause the current result to *not* be unique? (my guess: some date/time/timestamp)

Comment: @wildplasser I can't seem to get the duplicates removed out of the tabArtikel.ArtCode column, every row in this column needs to be unique, but at the tabVoorraadMutatie.VrdMutDatum it needs to show the most recent date compared to the tabArtikel.ArtCode. I hope I explained it correctly

Comment: So the `tabVoorraadMutatie.VrdMutDatum` is the column that distinguishes the duplicates?

Comment: @wildplasser yeah, for a lot of values from tabArtikel.ArtCode there are different VrdMutDatum values, like 21-11-2016 being the most recent one but also 11-11-2016, 10-09-2016, 12-06-2015 etc..

Comment: And you want only the most recent one? :: suppress the others.

Comment: @wildplasser yeah, we need to see only the most recent date, so we can see what values have not been edited in several years etc. If we display multiple dates for each ArtCode, we will reach over 100.000 lines

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Step#1 use table aliasses:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ta.ArtCode
        , ta.ArtOms
        , ldet.AldArtCodeBijLeverancier
        , ldet.AldInkoopPrijs
        , vrd.MagVoorraad
        , vrd.LocNaam
        , mut.VrdMutDatum
        , naw.NawFilNummer
FROM KingSystem.tabArtikel ta
        , KingSystem.tabArtikelLeverancier tal
        , KingSystem.tabArtikelLeverancierDetail ldet
        , KingSystem.tabNawFile naw
        , KingSystem.tabVoorraadMutatie mut
        , KingSystem.vwKMBVoorraad vrd
WHERE vrd.ArtGid = ta.ArtGid 
  AND tal.ArtLevArtGid = ta.ArtGid
  AND ldet.AldArtLevGid = tal.ArtLevGid
  AND mut.VrdMutArtGid = ta.ArtGid
  AND naw.NawFilNawGid = tal.ArtLevNawGid
  AND vrd.MagVoorraad>0 AND (ta.ArtCode Not Like 'V%' 
--      ORDER BY mut.VrdMutDatum DESC -- nonsens!
        ;
```

---

Step#2 : use JOIN-syntax (and remove the distinct):

---

```
SELECT -- DISTINCT
       ta.ArtCode
        , ta.ArtOms
        , ldet.AldArtCodeBijLeverancier
        , ldet.AldInkoopPrijs
        , vrd.MagVoorraad
        , vrd.LocNaam
        , mut.VrdMutDatum
        , naw.NawFilNummer
FROM KingSystem.tabArtikel ta
JOIN KingSystem.vwKMBVoorraad vrd ON vrd.ArtGid = ta.ArtGid
JOIN KingSystem.tabArtikelLeverancier tal ON tal.ArtLevArtGid = ta.ArtGid
JOIN KingSystem.tabArtikelLeverancierDetail ldet ON ldet.AldArtLevGid = tal.ArtLevGid
JOIN KingSystem.tabNawFile naw ON naw.NawFilNawGid = tal.ArtLevNawGid
JOIN KingSystem.tabVoorraadMutatie mut ON mut.VrdMutArtGid = ta.ArtGid
WHERE vrd.MagVoorraad>0 AND ta.ArtCode Not Like 'V%'
--      ORDER BY mut.VrdMutDatum DESC -- nonsens!
        ;
```

---

step#3 : add condition to suppress the old mutations:

---

```
SELECT -- DISTINCT
       ta.ArtCode
        , ta.ArtOms
        , ldet.AldArtCodeBijLeverancier
        , ldet.AldInkoopPrijs
        , vrd.MagVoorraad
        , vrd.LocNaam
        , mut.VrdMutDatum
        , naw.NawFilNummer
FROM KingSystem.tabArtikel ta
JOIN KingSystem.vwKMBVoorraad vrd
        ON vrd.ArtGid = ta.ArtGid
JOIN KingSystem.tabArtikelLeverancier tal
        ON tal.ArtLevArtGid = ta.ArtGid
JOIN KingSystem.tabArtikelLeverancierDetail ldet
        ON ldet.AldArtLevGid = tal.ArtLevGid
JOIN KingSystem.tabNawFile naw
        ON naw.NawFilNawGid = tal.ArtLevNawGid
JOIN KingSystem.tabVoorraadMutatie mut
        ON mut.VrdMutArtGid = ta.ArtGid
        AND NOT EXISTS( -- suppress older mutations; keeping only the most recent
        SELECT * FROM KingSystem.tabVoorraadMutatie mx
        WHERE mx.VrdMutArtGid = mut.VrdMutArtGid
        AND mx.VrdMutDatum > mut.VrdMutDatum
        )
WHERE vrd.MagVoorraad > 0 AND ta.ArtCode Not Like 'V%'
--      ORDER BY mut.VrdMutDatum DESC -- nonsens!
        ;
```

---

Voila! (that'll be approx 50 euro)

---

Step#4: reorder the columns, and add an `order by` clause

---

UPDATE: I removed the `DISTINCT` It servers no purpose, and can only hide possible errors (and introduce other,*more serious* errors)

Comment: Thanks, will try to implement your suggestion. Will leave feedback later today