# How to remove duplicates in one column and select the first top one only

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
select * from 
(select M.* from zstatistics M JOIN ZEntrycriteria C ON  M.coursecode=C.Course_code 
    where C.Maths <= @maths 
    AND C.Science <= @science 
    AND C.English <= @english 
    And C.Ict <= @ict 
    And C.History <= @history 
    And C.Geography <= @geography 
    And C.Art <= @Art 
UNION 
    select M.* from zsuggestions M JOIN ZEntrycriteria C ON M.coursecode=C.Course_code 
    where C.Maths <= @maths 
    AND C.Science <= @science 
    AND C.English <= @english 
    And C.Ict <= @ict 
    And C.History <= @history 
    And C.Geography <= @geography 
    And C.Art <= @Art
```

) t

```
ORDER BY sqrt( power(t.Maths - @maths, 2) + power(t.Science - @science,2) + power(t.English - @english,2) + power(t.Ict - @ict,2) + power(t.History-@history,2) + power(t.Geography - @geography,2) + power(t.Art - @Art,2))
```

The above sql query give the following answer.

```
SchoolName| CourseName| Maths| Science| English| History|Geography|Art|ICT

xyz       |  abcd     |45    |85      |85      |  95    |58       |65 |85

xyz       |  abcd     |85    |95      | 68     |80      |  100    |40 |80

kkk       |  ku       |60    |50      | 54     | 82     |82       |58 |95

.
.
.
```

As you can see now CourseName column has two "abcd" with different data. My question is how do i get only the top row with "abcd". I tried with "group by CourseName" and "Partition by" but doesnt work. Any help would be appreciated.

I think I found the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17507887/eliminating-duplicate-values-based-on-only-one-column-of-the-table)! but I do not understand how to use it on my scenario   (Sorry for bad English )

Comment: do you actually need the group by here?

Comment: hi actually yes. I just need one row with unique "coursecode"s . But rightnow i get multiple different rows with same "coursecode".

Comment: Why do you have a union?

Comment: That's not how group by works. You need to include each of the columns in the select list either in the group by clause or in an aggregation function such as sum, count, avg etc'

Comment: @Zohar Peled Can you suggest what i should do please

Comment: yes - change the group by. I don't know what values of the other columns you want to show so I can't suggest anything specific. (and nither does sql server, hence the error). If you could edit your question in include sample data and desired results it would be easier to answer.

Comment: @ Zohar Peled Thank you for the reply ...I have edited it .

Comment: Are you on MySql or Sql-Server?

Comment: @ Giorgos Altanis i m on Sql-Server (vs 2015)

Comment: So in general the answer provided by Vecchiasignora schould be OK. You didn't show us any input data, so one cannot tell for sure why there are two records there; but i suspect that you will almost always have two records (one from the first part of the union and one from the second) and you just want to get the minimum criterion of these. If this is correct there may be another version.

Comment: yes tables are correct and answer will always have multiple (duplicates of CourseName) rows with same "CourseName". So i need to figure out only to select the top one

Comment: Multiple or two?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
try this

select * from (select ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by CourseName order by  sqrt( power(t.Maths - @maths, 2) + power(t.Science - @science,2) + power(t.English - @english,2) + power(t.Ict - @ict,2) + power(t.History-@history,2) + power(t.Geography - @geography,2) + power(t.Art - @Art,2)) ) rownumb , t.* from 
(select M.* from zstatistics M JOIN ZEntrycriteria C ON  M.coursecode=C.Course_code 
    where C.Maths <= @maths 
    AND C.Science <= @science 
    AND C.English <= @english 
    And C.Ict <= @ict 
    And C.History <= @history 
    And C.Geography <= @geography 
    And C.Art <= @Art 
UNION 
    select M.* from zsuggestions M JOIN ZEntrycriteria C ON M.coursecode=C.Course_code 
    where C.Maths <= @maths 
    AND C.Science <= @science 
    AND C.English <= @english 
    And C.Ict <= @ict 
    And C.History <= @history 
    And C.Geography <= @geography 
    And C.Art <= @Art 
) t) a
where  a.rownumb=1
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But I am getting following error "Incorrect syntax near 'partiton'.
Incorrect syntax near 't'."

Comment: change partiton to partition

Comment: @ Vecchiasignora  so sorry that was embarrassing.. yes it is working now ..please just give me few mins to test it fully with data ..

Comment: yes it is working! Thank you very much ...Unfortunately i still can not up vote you as i am still a new member ...Thank you again