# How to select only one row of particular id? Not Solved with Distinct

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a SQL Server table `Restaurent` joined with `Product`:

```
SELECT 
    rm.RestaurantId, rm.RestaurantImage, rm.RestaurantName, 
    rm.RestaurantLocation,
    pm.ProductName, rm.IsActive,
    (6371 * acos(cos(radians(@userlat)) * cos(radians(RestaurantLatitude)) * cos(radians(RestaurantLongitude) - radians(@userlong)) + sin(radians(@userlat)) * sin(radians(RestaurantLatitude)))) AS distance 
FROM 
    HomeMadeFood.dbo.RestaurentMaster AS rm 
INNER JOIN
    ProductMaster AS pm ON pm.RestaurentId = rm.RestaurantId
GROUP BY 
    rm.RestaurantId
ORDER BY 
    distance ASC
```

This query returns output like this:

```
RestID     RestName      Distance    ProductName
-------------------------------------------------
  1         A             16           Demo1
  2         B             20           Demo2
  1         A             16           Demo3
  3         C             50           Demo4
```

My expected output should be like this

```
RestID     RestName      Distance    ProductName
-------------------------------------------------
   1         A             16           Demo1
   2         B             20           Demo2
   3         C             50           Demo4
```

If I use `group by` on `RestId` it throws an error on second column (Image)

Comment: Why Demo1 and not Demo3 for A?

Comment: Just want single time restaurant not more

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Eliminating duplicate values based on only one column of the table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17507887/eliminating-duplicate-values-based-on-only-one-column-of-the-table)

Answer (score 0):

The following fixes the error you see by moving all non-aggregated columns to the `group by` clause:

```
SELECT rm.RestaurantId, rm.RestaurantImage, rm.RestaurantName, rm.RestaurantLocation, pm.ProductName, rm.IsActive,
       ( 6371 * acos( cos( radians(@userlat) ) * cos( radians(RestaurantLatitude) ) * cos( radians(RestaurantLongitude) - radians(@userlong) ) + sin( radians(@userlat) ) * sin( radians(RestaurantLatitude) ) ) ) AS distance 
from HomeMadeFood.dbo.RestaurentMaster rm inner join
     ProductMaster pm 
     on pm.RestaurentId = rm.RestaurantId
group by rm.RestaurantId, rm.RestaurantImage, rm.RestaurantName, rm.RestaurantLocation, pm.ProductName, rm.IsActive,
         rm.RestaurantLongitude, rm.RestaurantLatitude
order by distance asc;
```

Your desired results are much simpler, so I would suggest:

```
SELECT rm.RestaurantId, rm.RestaurantName, rm.IsActive,
       ( 6371 * acos( cos( radians(@userlat) ) * cos( radians(RestaurantLatitude) ) * cos( radians(RestaurantLongitude) - radians(@userlong) ) + sin( radians(@userlat) ) * sin( radians(RestaurantLatitude) ) ) ) AS distance 
from HomeMadeFood.dbo.RestaurentMaster rm inner join
     ProductMaster pm 
     on pm.RestaurentId = rm.RestaurantId
group by rm.RestaurantId, rm.RestaurantName, rm.IsActive,
         rm.RestaurantLongitude, rm.RestaurantLatitude
order by distance asc;
```

Comment: @DevKriya . . . What does "not working" mean?  If you are still getting duplicates (particularly with the second query), then you might have duplicates in your restaurants table.

Answer (score 0):

As per my assumption, what you need is the first row with a particular id where distance is least.
Try this one.

```
WITH MyNewTable AS(
SELECT rm.RestaurantId,rm.RestaurantImage,rm.RestaurantName,rm.RestaurantLocation,pm.ProductName,rm.IsActive,( 6371 * acos( cos( radians(@userlat) ) * cos( radians(RestaurantLatitude) ) * cos( radians(RestaurantLongitude) - radians(@userlong) ) + sin( radians(@userlat) ) * sin( radians(RestaurantLatitude) ) ) ) AS distance,
ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY pm.RestaurentId ) AS rk 
FROM HomeMadeFood.dbo.RestaurentMaster AS rm 
INNER JOIN ProductMaster AS pm 
on pm.RestaurentId = rm.RestaurantId
ORDER BY distance ASC
) 
SELECT
*
FROM
MyNewTable
WHERE rk = 1
```

Let me know if it doesn't work.