# How can I get the top row when there's duplicate IDs in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm using join and union to retrieve data from multiple tables in SQL. I have some rows with duplicate IDs and I need to return just the top rows of those duplicate IDs rows and combine the data in a specific column in all the duplicate rows into one column in the top row returned. I can't use max(createDate) because they're duplicates in dates too.

This is my stored procedure:

```
  select distinct 

    table1.*,
    table2.*
  from 
    calsses table1 
  inner join documents table2 on table1.ID = table2.ID

union all

  select distinct 

    table3.*,
    table2.*
  from 
    exams table3 
  inner join documents table2 on table3.ID = table2.ID

  order by table2.Date desc
```

This is the result:

When I run this stored procedure I get rows with duplicate IDs.

[image: duplicate rows data_click here]

How can I return 1 row out of all the duplicate rows and combine the data in column "Exams" in the duplicate rows to the column "Exams" in the single returned row?

[image: Target data_click here]

Please advise. Thanks.

Comment: We can't see your tables, or data, so on it's own, this is difficult to answer. You reference the column `[Address]`, however, both queries are returning `[TableName].*` So, we have no idea where this column is located. Could you please update your question with some DDL and **consumable** Sample Data, as well as your expected results please. [How to post a T-SQL question](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Best+Practices/61537/).

Comment: There are probably close to 3 trillion (rough estimate) posts on the internet how to deal with duplicates in SQL. Have you tried google.com?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Eliminating duplicate values based on only one column of the table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17507887/eliminating-duplicate-values-based-on-only-one-column-of-the-table)

Comment: @JacobH It actually took a surprising amount of time to find a good duplicate.   Almost a minute.

Comment: Your code definitely does not match your query.  For instance, each query would have *two* columns named `id`, but your result set has only one.

Comment: The operation is `select distinct` is potentially different with different sets of columns. So it does matter very much which columns are included.

Answer (score 0):

I think that `XML PATH` is your statement.

If I understend your question you have two identical rows and you do not have any field to select one. So you one any of this rows but with `Address` field grouped.

```
select *, 
STUFF((SELECT '; ' + US.USR_NAME 
      FROM table_where_is_address twis
      WHERE twis.ID = aux.ID_to_join_with_correct_row
      FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '') as grouped_address
from (
    select distinct 
      table1.*,
      table2.*
    from calsses table1 
    inner join documents table2 on table1.ID = table2.ID
    union all
    select distinct 
      table3.*,
      table2.*
    from exams table3 
    inner join documents table2 on table3.ID = table2.ID
    order by table2.Date desc
) aux
```

This modified for your data model should work.

Answer (score 0):

Good article for concatenate row values 
https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/t-sql-programming/concatenating-row-values-in-transact-sql/