# How to remove duplicates from a query based on a specific coulmn in sql server

Tags: sql-server

I have a query that returns the following data
As you can see theres duplicate customer numbers but different data for the other columns

[image]

I am trying to remove the duplicate of the ticket number it doesnt matter which of the duplicate row remains,i only want to show unique tickets as following
[image]

i tried doing:

```
select DISTINCT t.Ticket 
,t.customerNO
,tt.Name
,t.Order
,tt.date
from table 1 t inner join table 2 on t.id=tt.id
```

i tried to filter the ticket column with distinct but its still giving me duplicate rows as the first picture above,Then i realized that duplicate checks the entire row because the rest of the other columns are different data.

what can i do to achieve this ? without having to use cte

Comment: Why dont you just put the Ticket field as unique ? https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_unique.asp

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Eliminating duplicate values based on only one column of the table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17507887/eliminating-duplicate-values-based-on-only-one-column-of-the-table)

Comment: because i dont have access to alter the table

Answer (score 1):

This should return the first ticket for each Name which is what the desired output looks like you want.

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT
        *
        ,Row_number() OVER(PARTITION BY [Name] ORDER BY Ticket ASC) AS [Row]
    FROM <TABLE>
) Ordered
WHERE [Row]=1
```